# Guice: AbstractModule vs. ServletModule

Tags: java, servlets, guice

I found examples on the web using both `AbstractModule` and `ServletModule` classes as the super type while using Guice. I'd like to know which one I need to use in what scenario in web applications.

I'm working on a RESTful web service (using Jersey) and the artifact is a WAR file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServletModule](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/servlet/ServletModule.html) extends AbstractModule, so general bindings that just use `bind`, `install`, or `@Provides` methods are free to use one or the other. However, ServletModule also provides servlet-specific bindings, particularly `filter` and `serve` (with corresponding variants `filterRegex` and `serveRegex`) to be called from `configureServlets`.

In Guice, Modules don't have to specify which Modules they work with or employ as dependencies; you are free to use AbstractModule and ServletModule together, and they can rely on one anothers' bindings as long as they are installed in the same Injector. However, you'll at least need a ServletModule for configuring the serving paths.

An example of a ServletModule powering a Jersey REST service: [[link]](https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes//posts/jersey_guice_rest_api#TOC-Gluing-everything-together-DI-)